# Finding next matching hunk when using git add --patch

Tags: git, git-add

I find the use of **git add --patch** very useful for my work-flow sometimes, like when I need to revise lots before anything is ready to commit, especially with documentation.  If I have a large number of hunks to sift through, the search feature via **/** is helpful, but I have not discovered any way to search for the next hunk matching my regex without retyping the regex each time.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git add` is not a bash shell so you can't just recall history. Just copy the regex to your clipboard before executing it. You can then paste it in next time.

Comment: I was hoping for something built-in and less tedious, like how **n** works in vi or maybe just hitting Enter at the "search for regex?" prompt (which does not work).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't exist. You have a very specific use case. I'm not sure if that will ever make it as a feature of the current `patch` mechanism. Perhaps if git gets another mechanism for patch additions via bash itself we'll be able to just up-arrow to what we did before. There's value in what you want.

Comment: Well knowing the feature doesn't exist is better than wondering if I've overlooked something.  I originally checked the man page to see if there was a command-line option to auto-select all hunks matching a regex -- that would be slick.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) (which is readline for any command), e.g. like this:

```
rlwrap git add --patch
```